# How can I get Launchbar to open the Wireless Diagnostic app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, utilities, launchbar

I use [Launchbar](http://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) *Version 5.5 (1008)* to start programs from the keyboard and can't figure out how to start one specific app that comes with Mountain Lion *10.8.4 Build 12E55*.

Has anyone figured out how to launch the /System/Library/CoreServices/Wireless Diagnostic.app by assigning a custom shortcut or custom indexing rule?

---

I suspect the fact that the app needs an administrator password to run is messing up the indexing or the launching of the app, but can't be sure. To get Launchbar to index the CoreServices, I added the path /System/Library/Coreservices to the **Specific Places** and it finds other tools in CoreServices but not the one app I want.

[image]

I also tried letting the index rule **Search Everywhere** and selected *Include applications inside the Library* folders.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the developer and got a very clear reply. The application has a white list to avoid putting unknown CoreServices into play, so the steps I took to index that folder were for naught. The 5.5.1 update to the app fixes this one tool.

If you can't update or want to learn how to index this file manually, read on...

I needed to instead use the Launchbar Custom List function to explicitly index the services I desired.

[image: LaunchBar Index — Custom List]

Also, the developer has a practice of updating the white list once Apple's update can be tested, so unless you need something like I did right after a new OS is released, just waiting for a LaunchBar update might also solve this problem in the future.